# Jet Pack Plugin for Wordpress: Changing site URL

Tags: wordpress, indexing

I am using the Jetpack plugin for Wordpress

Now when you install and activate the plugin, they ask you "Authorize the Jetpack plugin for [this] site"

I want to change my domain name of my wordpress site - Will this affect the jetpack plugin in any way? Will I need to uninstall and reinstall the plugin again?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-jetpack-by-wordpresscom-changed-site-url-getting-jetpack-error) WordPress forum discussion, someone moved to a new domain and Jetpack started saying "unknown_token: It looks like your Jetpack connection is broken".

This is the answer the user got from support:

> "Since you've changed your URL, reconnecting the site will create a
>   new site id in Jetpack and will start a new stats history. I'm afraid
>   there's no way to merge the old stats back in to the new one that will
>   be created yet, but this might be possible in the future."

Comment: thank you very much - So your suggestion is that I first migrate my site and then install the plugin?

Comment: I guess you could try it if you don't mind losing stats history later when you switch to new domain.

Comment: yeah i don't really care about stats. The current site is just a test site. I am interested in the forms, shortcodes and content

Comment: Found another comment about moving domain and jetpack at http://wisedollar.org/changing-your-blogs-url/ where one commenter said "The one thing that was probably corrupted by the move was my jetpack plugin. I simply deleted it and re-installed it to fix that problem. I did lose my stats but I can live with that. "

Comment: ok thanks, think it is safe to say that I should reinstall it again. thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you change your domain name for your wordpress site, the jetpack plugin might get affected. However, jetpack plugin got some crashes when new update or changes is there.
For reference, check out the link below.
http://www.themesrush.com/wordpress-jetpack-twitter-widget-error/